# PHP - Count how many results are displayed in foreach

Tags: php, mysql

With the `foreach` loop, I wanna count how many results are displayed. For example, if it's displaying

```
Jack Ane
Steve Jobs
Sara Bill
```

I want to echo that there are `3` results.

Likewise, if it's like

```
Marc Kil
Bill Smith
```

I want to echo that there are `2` results.

It's a bit tricky for me becasue this is my code:

```
<div>
        <?php
        $container = array();
        if (is_array($row))
        {
            foreach ($row as $data) {
                if(!isset($container[$data->first_name .  $data->last_name])) {
                    $container[$data->first_name . $data->last_name] = $data;
                    echo $data->first_name . " " .$data->last_name . "</div>";
                }
            }
        }
        ?>

    </p>
</div>
```

How exactly would I be able to do that? Since these values are coming straight from the database, I was thinking of doing a database count but there are duplicate values in the database since I'm logging the views of users with the first and the last name. So when I try to do it, say for example there are `20` `Jack Ane` in my database. Then it shows me all of the `20` Jack Ane's instead of just one because I just want it once.

Sorry if it's confusing.

Thanks.

Comment: Just eliminate the duplicates from your database query and you don't need the if test, and can simply count the results

Comment: I have been doing it with Codeigniter. I can't get it to work. 
`$count_log_value_users =  $this->db->get_where('log_table', array('pid' => $pid, 'uid !=' => 0))->num_rows();`

Comment: You can use `if ($query->num_rows() == 0) { }`

Comment: Does CI's DataMapper support DISTINCT in queries?

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes, it does. `$this->db->distinct();` However, it's not working for me.

Comment: what is your CI query that sends $row into view

Comment: Can't you simply use count($container) after the loop with the code in your question?

Comment: What does this have to do with `foreach`? Aren't you just asking how to output how many elements are in `$row` (better called `$rows`!)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I traditional use the count() to do that if you dont use any :

```
foreach ($row as $data) {
    if(!isset($container[$data->first_name .  $data->last_name])) {
        $container[$data->first_name . $data->last_name] = $data;
            echo $data->first_name . " " .$data->last_name . "</div>";
    }
}
echo "Results: " . count($row);
```

Hope that help you.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to rewrite your query. If you will do this in right way, you will get faster solution, with no needs to new array and unnecessary "isset" checks.

The reason you get duplicated data from query may be:
1 - Wrong query logic
2 - Query is OK, but you need to use DISTINCT or GROUP BY to remove duplicates

If you use PDO, you can then get number of returned rows just by using rowCount() method

```
$sql="SELECT * from table WHERE blablabla";
$result = $this->db->query($sql);
$result->rowCount(); // here
```

Then you can fetch $result->fetchAll(); and print data.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will take a note of this. Wish I could select all the answers as the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can to do a `SELECT DISTINCT` or a `GROUP BY` across the two columns to have the database do the work and eliminate the duplicate checking in your `PHP`. To do this you can use something like the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT first_name, last_name FROM users;

SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users GROUP BY first_name, last_name;
```

`DISTINCT` is more succinct while `GROUP BY` supports more flexibility.

In your example, since you are building an associative array, you can just do a `count()` after the loop, but you will have cleaner code if you have the database do it:

```
$count = count($container);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do an easy variable that increments inside your foreach that gives you the exact count, then use the variable to create actions depending on it's value. Because if you count the container and you wish to filter out the results inside the container, you won't get the filtered amount.

```
<?php
    $container = array();
    if (is_array($row))
    {
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($row as $data) {
            if(!isset($container[$data->first_name .  $data->last_name])) {
                $container[$data->first_name . $data->last_name] = $data;
                echo $data->first_name . " " .$data->last_name . "</div>";
                $count++;
            }
        }
    }
    if ($count > 0) {
        echo "There were $count results.";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
echo "Results: " . count($container);
```